# ServiceStack: POST body content as NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, servicestack

In a ServiceStack service or filter, is there any way to get access to the `NameValueCollection` parsed from a URLEncoded POST content?

While I understand that it is parsed into the DTO as appropriate, sometimes it is valuable to have access to the arbitrary values in the name value collection.

I don't mind having ServiceStack parse and fill the DTO—I just also want to see the raw `NameValueCollection` (or equivalent data structure if ServiceStack uses its own parsing mechanism).

Answer (score 3):

Inside a Service you can access the POST'ed data with:

```
var htmlPostVar = base.Request.FormData["postName"];
```

See the [Access HTTP specific features in services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Access-HTTP-specific-features-in-services) for more info on how to access HTTP Request and Response info from inside services.

Comment: I had read that page many times, and never noticed the `FormData` feature....  The only thing that comes close is in the source code example for filters where it says `httpReq.Form["htmlFormParam"];` but that is buried in the code example, and doesn't explain itself.

Comment: That's because I just updated it :) this info is spread across many answers in StackOverflow, I figured it was about time that it made it to the wiki.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.  I love the tool, and have read a lot of the code base, but sometimes finding the right documentation or best practice can be tricky.

Comment: np :) This is exactly what we use StackOverflow for, to build up a knowledge base with Q's people have that aren't in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The `Service` base class gives you access to the `Request` and you can find the POST content in `FormData` which is a `NameValueCollection`.

```
Request.FormData
```